# How to update a widget data?

Tags: widgets

I have a image widget and I want to update image url programmatically in php.. I will use a cron job and it is not a problem but I can not update the image url. When I try to update it with query, the widget's option_value turns to:

```
a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

Comment: Is that the value the widget saves as? Or what it looks like after your attempt to update it? Can you include the code you used to attempt this? If you're needing to update an image URL in code regularly, is it really wise to store it in the  widget and not a theme mod or option?

Comment: I foud the solution=> 
update_option( 'widget_media_image', array ( 2 => array ( 'title' => 'My Title', 'url' => 'https://example.com/image.jpg' ), '_multiwidget' => 1 ) );  
Thanks for your interest Tom.